# Sudoku debugging issue

Tags: java, debugging, multidimensional-array, return, sudoku

I'm working on a program that is supposed to take as input a solved Sudoku Puzzle and return if it is a valid solution or not (true or false).
My code is written and running with a few helper methods.

The isSolution method runs through 4 different things to check if the solution is valid or not. 
I've written a valid solution as input that should return true. 
When I check each of these 4 elements separately, they return true, when I check them together, they return false (which is wrong)

I've spent hours testing them separately, together and in different combinations. 
I've tried with different inputs.
I can't figure out why it's returning false when it should be returning true.

Any help would be amazingly appreciated! Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int [][] solvedPuzzle = {
  {8,3,5,4,1,6,9,2,7},
  {2,9,6,8,5,7,4,3,1},
  {4,1,7,2,9,3,6,5,8},

  {5,6,9,1,3,4,7,8,2},
  {1,2,3,6,7,8,5,4,9},
  {7,4,8,5,2,9,1,6,3},

  {6,5,2,7,8,1,3,9,4},
  {9,8,1,3,4,5,2,7,6},
  {3,7,4,9,6,2,8,1,5}
  };

 System.out.println(isSolution(solvedPuzzle));
 }


////// Checks if the input is a valid sudoku solution
/* The solvedPuzzle input is a valid solution, so this method should return true.
 * Each of the elements in this method return true when tested individually, but for some reason, 
 * when I run them all together, the method returns false
 */
public static boolean isSolution(int [][] solvedPuzzle){
  //Checks if the rows and columns have 9 ints 
  if (solvedPuzzle.length != 9 || solvedPuzzle[0].length !=9){
    return false;
  }

//Checks if every column is made up of unique entries
  for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
    if (uniqueEntries(getColumn(solvedPuzzle, j)) !=true){
      System.out.println("HERE!"); //these are just here to try to figure out WHERE I've gone wrong
      return false;
    }
  }

  //Checks if every row is made up of unique entries 
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    if (uniqueEntries(solvedPuzzle[i]) !=true){
              System.out.println("HERE!!!");
      return false;
    }
  }

  //Checks if every sub 3x3 grid is made up of unique entries
  for (int x = 0; x < 9; x = x+3){
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y = y+3){
        if (uniqueEntries(flatten(subGrid(solvedPuzzle, x,y,3))) != true){
                  System.out.println("HERE22");
        return false;
      }
    } 
  }  

return true;
}




///Below are the helper methods

////// Creates a smaller grid of size m starting at indexI,indexJ (x,y). 
public static int [][] subGrid(int [][] original, int indexI, int indexJ, int m){
  int [][] subGrid = new int [m][m]; 
  for (int i = indexI; i < indexI+m ; i++){
       for (int j = indexJ; j < indexJ+m ; j++){ 
            subGrid [i - indexI][j - indexJ] = original[i][j];
       }
  }
  return subGrid;
}

////// Sorts the intergers in a 1D array in asceding order
public static int [] sort(int [] originalArray){
  int temp;
  for(int i = 0; i < originalArray.length - 1; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < originalArray.length - 1; j++){
          if(originalArray[j] > originalArray[j+1]){
              temp = originalArray[j];
              originalArray[j] = originalArray[j+1];
              originalArray[j+1] = temp;
          }
      }
  }
  return(originalArray);
}

////// Checks if the intergers in a 1D array are all unique by first using the sort method
public static boolean uniqueEntries(int [] original){
  int [] sorted = sort(original);
  for (int i = 0; i < original.length-1; i++){
    if (sorted[i+1] == sorted[i]) {
        return false;
      }
     } 
  return true;
}

////// Takes a 2D array where each subarray is of the same size and creates a 1D array made up of the i-th element of each sub array
public static int [] getColumn(int [][] original, int indexJ){
  int [] column = new int[original[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < original[0].length; i++){
      column[i] = original[i][indexJ];
    } 
  return column;
}

////// takes a 2D array and flattens it into a 1D array 
public static int [] flatten(int [][] original){
  int [] flattenedArray = new int[original.length*original[0].length];
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < original.length; j++) {
      flattenedArray[counter] = original[i][j];
      counter++;
      }
  }
  return flattenedArray;
}
```

Comment: why are you using `i < original.length-1` and not  `i < original.length` ? I think this is a problem. Have you tried to debug and find where does it return `false`?

Comment: if you swap the block that `//Checks if every row is made up of unique entries` with the block that `//Checks if every sub 3x3 grid is made up of unique entries' within your `isSolution` method you will see that it works. That should give you a hint where the issue is!

Comment: @Rakim  It worked! ...still don't really understand why, just switching the order of those steps seems to have solved the problem without changing anything else in the code.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @s.gau I ll post an actual answer to see why!

Answer (score 1):

if you check your puzzle before and after running `//Checks if every row is made up of unique entries` you will see that you are actually changing the original format of your puzzle. So the next test is not going to run over the original puzzle but a sorted one! If you add a simple loop before and after the second test you will understand what I am talking about

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){ //ADD THAT LOOP BEFORE AND AFTER THE TEST
    for (int j = 0; j<9; j++) {
        System.out.print(solvedPuzzle[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println('\n');

  //Checks if every row is made up of unique entries 
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    if (uniqueEntries(solvedPuzzle[i]) !=true){
              System.out.println("HERE!!!");
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<9; j++) {
        System.out.print(solvedPuzzle[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

the code above will help you visualise what the puzzle looks before and after the test. A test should never change the format/contents/attributes of anything tested. The results of the above will be:

```
835416927
296857431
417293658
569134782
123678549
748529163
652781394
981345276
374962815


123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
```

As you can see the original puzzle is not "original" anymore.

So as I told you on my comment, flipping the tests around will NOT actually fix the problem. Instead the bug will still be produced; but without any tests to run after it is not going to affect the CURRENT code.

Hope that helps

**EDIT**: I don't know if I will be online later on; so in the case that even that hint didn't help you find the bug so I am also going to give you the solution :p

The issue is that you are using the `sort()` method that doesn't ONLY return the array sorted BUT ALSO actually sorts the input array! SO in order to avoid that you simply need to pass in a copy of the array instead of the array itself whenever you are calling the sort method:

```
    ////// Checks if the intergers in a 1D array are all unique by first using the sort method
    public static boolean uniqueEntries(int [] original){
        int [] sorted = sort(original.clone()); //pass in a copy of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < original.length-1; i++){
            if (sorted[i+1] == sorted[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```